# How does Angular know what to inject if I don't specify strings?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, language-implementation

Consider this code:

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    ...
  });
```

I know that to avoid problems with injection when the JS is minified, the array form of Dependency Injection should be used:

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    ...
  }]);
```

But how does Angular know in the *first* case (non-array) what to inject? What if I use [`.controller('MainCtrl', function (scop)`](https://thinkster.io/egghead/scope-vs-scope/) instead of `$scope`? Does it parse my JS and look for function parameter names that match some of its providers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that the `controller`'s function is a parameter of the function `controller`. That allows Angular to get that function in a variable and analyze its parameters, and with that angular makes a list of the services that need to be injected.

In the code bellow you can see what Angular does behind the scenes in order to match those parameters:

```
var FN_ARGS = /^function\s*[^\(]*\(\s*([^\)]*)\)/m;
var FN_ARG_SPLIT = /,/;
var FN_ARG = /^\s*(_?)(\S+?)\1\s*$/;
var STRIP_COMMENTS = /((\/\/.*$)|(\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/))/mg;

function annotate (fn) {
  var $inject = [];
  fn = fn.toString();
  var first = fn.replace(STRIP_COMMENTS, '');
  var second = first.match(FN_ARGS)[1];
  var third = second.split(FN_ARG_SPLIT);
  third.forEach(function (arg) {
    arg.replace(FN_ARG, function (all, underscore, name) {
      $inject.push(name);
    });
  });
  return $inject;
}
```

Comment: This is correct. They take the function, turn it into a string, and look at the dependencies. Then match it to service/factory modules in the app. It breaks in minification because the dependencies get renamed to single letters, and won't be able to map to corresponding app modules.

Comment: `fn = fn.toString();` ← this.

Comment: @ZackArgyle If you use ng-annotate (e.g. via grunt-ng-annotate, ngannotate-rails, etc.), you can leave off the list of strings and *not* break minification.